# How to optimize spatial join?

Tags: sql-server, spatial, sql-server-2022

The SQL Server is pretty fast finding neighbors of a geography in a spatial index. Either it is finding [nearest neighbors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/query-spatial-data-for-nearest-neighbor?view=sql-server-ver16) or all neighbors in specific area, the query result is instant.

I am not able to get the result so fast, if I need to find neighbors for multiple points.

I guess the business case is widely recognized. Let's say we have one table with coordinates of locations (it can be stores, restaurants, offices, etc.) and one table with coordinates of the users and their travel distance.

In the context of the user, if I am in the center of the city and want to travel 5 miles - getting all locations in my range is fast. But in the context of a business, if I want to send email to all users who are in range of my stores, the query is pretty slow.

Here is some sample date with several queries trying to find all users - locations pairs.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Locations;

CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    [UserID] BIGINT pRIMARY KEY
   ,[Latitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
   ,[Longitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
    -- this is our user point and user's travel distances in meters
   ,[CenterGeography] GEOGRAPHY
   ,[TravelDistance] INT
    -- this is the [CenterGeography] * [TravelDistance]
   ,[AreaGeography] GEOGRAPHY
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Users_CenterGeography] ON #Users
(
    [CenterGeography]
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Users_AreaGeography] ON #Users
(
    [AreaGeography]
);

CREATE TABLE #Locations
(
     [LocationID] BIGINT pRIMARY KEY
    ,[CenterGeography] GEOGRAPHY
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Locations_AreaGeography] ON #Locations
(
    [CenterGeography]
);

INSERT INTO #Users ([UserID], [Latitude], [Longitude], [TravelDistance])
SELECT CenterLocations.[CenterID] * 10000 + U.[value]
      ,CenterLocations.[Lat] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001
      ,CenterLocations.[Long] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001
      ,1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 * 1609
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000) U
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (1, 13.404954, 52.520008)
          ,(2, 13.737262, 51.050407)
          ,(3, 6.783333, 51.233334)
          ,(4, 9.183333, 48.783333)
          ,(5, 6.953101, 50.935173)
) CenterLocations ([CenterID], [Lat], [Long]);

UPDATE #Users
SET [CenterGeography] = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326) 
   ,[AreaGeography] = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326).STBuffer([TravelDistance]);

INSERT INTO #Locations ([LocationID], [CenterGeography])
SELECT CenterLocations.[CenterID] * 10000 + L.[value]
      ,GEOGRAPHY::Point(CenterLocations.[Lat] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001, CenterLocations.[Long] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001, 4326)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) L
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (1, 13.404954, 52.520008)
          ,(2, 13.737262, 51.050407)
          ,(3, 6.783333, 51.233334)
          ,(4, 9.183333, 48.783333)
          ,(5, 6.953101, 50.935173)
) CenterLocations ([CenterID], [Lat], [Long]);

RETURN;

-- varint 00 - get locations for one user (the spatial index is used without the hint)

    SELECT U.[UserID]
          ,L.[LocationID]
    FROM #Users U 
    INNER JOIN #Locations L WITH (INDEX = [IX_#Locations_AreaGeography])
        ON U.[CenterGeography].STDistance(L.[CenterGeography] ) <= U.[TravelDistance]
    WHERE U.[UserID] = 10001;

-- variant 01 - intersect -- spatial index not used -- 83 seconds

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

    SELECT U.[UserID]
          ,L.[LocationID]
    INTO #TEST
    FROM #Users U
    INNER JOIN #Locations L
        ON U.[AreaGeography].STIntersects(L.[CenterGeography]) = 1;

-- variant 02 - STDistance -- spatila index is used -- 62 seconds

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

    SELECT U.[UserID]
          ,L.[LocationID]
    INTO #TEST
    FROM #Users U
    INNER JOIN #Locations L WITH (INDEX = [IX_#Locations_AreaGeography])
        ON U.[CenterGeography].STDistance(L.[CenterGeography] ) <= U.[TravelDistance];

-- variant 03 - STDistance -- only works if the <= argument is static but it is executed for 13 seconds

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;

    SELECT U.[UserID]
          ,L.[LocationID]
    INTO #TEST
    FROM #Users U WITH (INDEX = [IX_#Users_CenterGeography])
    INNER JOIN #Locations L 
        ON U.[CenterGeography].STDistance(L.[CenterGeography] ) <= 6437 --U.[TravelDistance]
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The example uses [GENERATE_SERIES](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/generate-series-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), so it requires SQL Server 2022. I can create any type of index or materialized any kind of geography object, so one can change the tables definitions if you want. For now, it seems the fastest technique is `variant 03` but it requires hard coded travel distance to work, which basically means I am not returning the correct data.

I want to know is there a way to optimize such queries using spatial data in SQL Server or I need to find alternative to get better performance (for example to pre-calalculate with triggers the locations in range per each user).

Comment: Have you tried buffering the location points to turn them into polygons and then doing a Contains search ?

Comment: Usually I would use `ST_Dwithin` but I don't know if sql-server has that operator - if you really want speed then it might be worth switching to postgres with postgis extension.

Comment: @IanTurton Perhaps a little pre-mature to say switching database systems will improve performance when you're unfamiliar with the one being switched from.

Comment: I have 20 years of experience in trying to make both DB go fast for spatial queries and I have never got good performance in sql-server (and don't even mention oracle)

Comment: @gotqn Admittedly I'm not an expert on geospatial querying, having only done it a handful of times.  So I'd have to sit down and spend some time closely looking at your example. But by your verbal description, I don't understand the difference of looking for "*all instances of ObjectA by geography relative to ObjectB*" vs "*all instances of ObjectB by geography relative to ObjectA*" (to generalize my understanding of your goal)?

Comment: @IanTurton If you have 20 years experience in SQL Server, I'm surprised you're unsure of what spatial operators it offers.

Comment: @IanTurton it's not so easy to change the used database in my case :-) it's 15+ years app :-) so, in postgres such queries are fast?

Comment: @J.D. you can play with my sample data - I believe it is self explaining; there a lot of geospatial functions and some other settings on the spatial indexes which I try, but nothing helped... I guess that the engine might be just not good with these types of queries, which is again valid answer for me - to stop trying optimize this

Comment: @gotqn If I get time I will try playing with it. But by your description it sounds like you're trying to do the same thing just in the opposite direction. Idk why that would be any different programmatically. I would also be surprised if PostgreSQL was measurably more performant for this use case than SQL Server, but anything's possible.

Comment: Well, we have users with travel range. And we need to find all locations in their range. That's it.

Comment: @gotqn Ah I think I understand. You're not trying to find how many users who are currently within a fixed distance of a business. Rather you want to know which users current position + their range (a dynamic distance) would overlap a specific business?

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64 Yes, it is the first variant01 in my example.

Comment: I guess thete are many more users than locations (could be wrong) if you convert the locations to circles ( temp table ? ) and then search which points / users are within the circles that is often faster

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample data, it seems that variant 02 is the fastest - 62 seconds on my environment.

Alternative solution is to implement bounding box alone. In order to to that we need to calculate the coordinates of the its min and max points based on user's travel distance.

This box will be not accurate - it will include more points (locations) which will be filtered using more precise method - in our case `STDistance`.

The issue is to ensure all points are included in the initial bounding box. I have tested different formulas to solve this and this is the best one I have found:

```
DECLARE @BufferPercentage DECIMAL(5, 2) = 1.10;

UPDATE #Users
SET [MinLatitude] = Latitude - (([TravelDistance] * @BufferPercentage) / 111111.0)
   ,[MaxLatitude] = Latitude + (([TravelDistance] * @BufferPercentage) / 111111.0)
   ,[MinLongitude] = Longitude - (([TravelDistance]  * @BufferPercentage ) / (COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * 6371000 * PI() / 180))
   ,[MaxLongitude] = Longitude + (([TravelDistance]  * @BufferPercentage ) / (COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * 6371000 * PI() / 180))
```

We are 10% of each travel distance value. The longitude formula is based on this:

> Longitude Modification Factor: The Earth's circumference is not the
> same at all latitudes. Near the equator, the circumference is greater,
> and it reduces as you move toward the poles. This means a degree of
> longitude represents a greater distance at the equator than it does at
> higher latitudes. To account for this, the formula uses
> COS(RADIANS(Latitude)). The cosine of the latitude gives us a scaling
> factor that decreases from 1 at the equator (0 degrees latitude, where
> the cosine is 1) to 0 at the poles (90 degrees latitude, where the
> cosine is 0).
>
> Earth’s Mean Radius (in meters): 6371000 represents the mean radius of
> the Earth in meters. It's an average value that balances out the
> equatorial and polar radii, providing a standard value to use in
> spherical Earth calculations.
>
> Radians to Degrees Conversion: Since a degree is a measure of angular
> distance and the Earth is approximately spherical, we need to convert
> the travel distance from meters to degrees of longitude. To do this,
> we divide the distance by the Earth's circumference at the given
> latitude and convert radians to degrees using PI() / 180, because
> there are 2 * PI radians in a full circle and thus PI() / 180 radians
> in one degree.

The new code completes for **3 seconds** on my machine, but please not if you are using this, that the results might be not correct as we are using some % add to travel distance as the Earth surface is not perfect sphere.

If someone can share more precise formula it will be nice.

Here is the whole code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Users;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Locations;

CREATE TABLE #Users
(
    [UserID] BIGINT pRIMARY KEY
   ,[Latitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
   ,[Longitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
    -- this is our user point and user's travel distances in meters
   ,[CenterGeography] GEOGRAPHY
   ,[TravelDistance] INT
    -- this is the [CenterGeography] * [TravelDistance]
   ,[AreaGeography] GEOGRAPHY
   --
   ,[MinLatitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
   ,[MaxLatitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
   ,[MinLongitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
   ,[MaxLongitude] DECIMAL(9, 6)
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Users_CenterGeography] ON #Users
(
    [CenterGeography]
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Users_AreaGeography] ON #Users
(
    [AreaGeography]
);

CREATE TABLE #Locations
(
     [LocationID] BIGINT pRIMARY KEY
    ,[CenterGeography] GEOGRAPHY
);

CREATE SPATIAL INDEX [IX_#Locations_AreaGeography] ON #Locations
(
    [CenterGeography]
);

INSERT INTO #Users ([UserID], [Latitude], [Longitude], [TravelDistance])
SELECT CenterLocations.[CenterID] * 10000 + U.[value]
      ,CenterLocations.[Lat] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001
      ,CenterLocations.[Long] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001
      ,1 + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 5 * 1609
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 1000) U
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (1, 13.404954, 52.520008)
          ,(2, 13.737262, 51.050407)
          ,(3, 6.783333, 51.233334)
          ,(4, 9.183333, 48.783333)
          ,(5, 6.953101, 50.935173)
) CenterLocations ([CenterID], [Lat], [Long]);

UPDATE #Users
SET [CenterGeography] = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326) 
   ,[AreaGeography] = GEOGRAPHY::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], 4326).STBuffer([TravelDistance]);

INSERT INTO #Locations ([LocationID], [CenterGeography])
SELECT CenterLocations.[CenterID] * 10000 + L.[value]
      ,GEOGRAPHY::Point(CenterLocations.[Lat] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001, CenterLocations.[Long] + ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000 * 0.0001, 4326)
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 100) L
CROSS APPLY
(
    VALUES (1, 13.404954, 52.520008)
          ,(2, 13.737262, 51.050407)
          ,(3, 6.783333, 51.233334)
          ,(4, 9.183333, 48.783333)
          ,(5, 6.953101, 50.935173)
) CenterLocations ([CenterID], [Lat], [Long]);

RETURN;

    
    DECLARE @BufferPercentage DECIMAL(5, 2) = 1.10;

    UPDATE #Users
    SET [MinLatitude] = Latitude - (([TravelDistance] * @BufferPercentage) / 111111.0)
       ,[MaxLatitude] = Latitude + (([TravelDistance] * @BufferPercentage) / 111111.0)
       ,[MinLongitude] = Longitude - (([TravelDistance]  * @BufferPercentage ) / (COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * 6371000 * PI() / 180))
       ,[MaxLongitude] = Longitude + (([TravelDistance]  * @BufferPercentage ) / (COS(RADIANS(Latitude)) * 6371000 * PI() / 180))

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TEST3;

    SELECT U.[UserID], L.[LocationID]
    INTO #TEST
    FROM #Users U
    INNER JOIN #Locations L 
        ON L.[CenterGeography].Long >= U.MinLongitude
        AND L.[CenterGeography].Long <= U.MaxLongitude
        AND L.[CenterGeography].Lat >= U.MinLatitude
        AND L.[CenterGeography].Lat <= U.MaxLatitude

    SELECT  U.[UserID], L.[LocationID]
    INTO #TEST3
    FROM #TEST A
    INNER JOIN #Users U
        ON A.[UserID] = U.[UserID]
    INNER JOIN #Locations L
        ON A.LocationID = L.LocationID
    WHERE U.[CenterGeography].STDistance(L.[CenterGeography]) <= U.[TravelDistance]
```